# How to change an image position programatically without SetLeft?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have searched before and I thought `Canvas.SetLeft(image, double)` would be the answer but it ain't doing anything

```
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\alu\Desktop\caballos_jpg\serie_2\02.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
imgCb01.Source = myBitmapImage;
Canvas.SetLeft(imgCb01, 152d);//This aint working
Canvas.SetTop(imgCb01, 285.0);//This aint working
Thickness margin = imgCb01.Margin;//I thought this lines would move my image
margin.Left = (imgCb01.Margin.Left) + 5;//slightly to the right
imgCb01.Margin = margin;//and they do but they are hiding (TT-TT) ...
```

So I have this code, neither `SetLeft` nor `SetTop` work, and I thought I could do the trick modifying the margin but then the image moves "forward" while the image control keeps its position so it looks like the image has just became invisible.

Comment: Did you put your imgCb01 into Canvas control? Canvas.SetTop is an attached property and do nothing if control is not inside Canvas control.

Comment: It's also weird how you build you user interface. People usually don't use absolute coordinates in WPF as in winforms, but use Grid, StackPanel and etc. to make a layout.

Comment: Yes it's inside the canvas Grid/Canvas/Image, yeah I "know"(Im new to wpf tho... :'D) the position numbers are just some weird random numbers so I could notice if the image was "moving"

Comment: Check out the following sample https://www.dotnetperls.com/canvas-wpf

Comment: As a note, `Canvas.imgCb01.SetLeft(imgCb01, 152d);` is nonsense. It should be `Canvas.SetLeft(imgCb01, 152d);` If that doesn't work, the Image element is not a child of a Canvas element. Note also that you don't need to call BeginInit and EndInit. BitmapImage has a constructor that takes an Uri argument: `imgCb01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));`. Finally, you shouldn't be creating UI elements in code at all. Use DataTemplates. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: Canvas.imgCb01.SetLeft(imgCb01, 152d); is a typo I made asking sorry ill change that, notice that I also made a Canvas.SetTop();, I actually do need to call BeginInit and EndInit as stated on the learn.microsoft.com, I dont think I could really explain the reason in english, but If i comment those 2 lines the Image Control would get plain white NaN color image, finnally thanks a lot for the doc on the data templates.

Comment: You only need Begin/EndInit if you set any other property than UriSource. Otherwise you must have done something else wrong.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-use-a-bitmapimage  "// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block" idk but im a noob and im just following the docs...

Comment: That is only relevant if you actually set the UriSource property, which you don't do when you call the other constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think it was just some weird random bug from Microsoft Visual Studio, I just started again in other PC copying the XAML and it just worked fine... sorry to bother you :')